# How to find a root to leaf path which is equal to a sum(pathsum problem) in Prolog?

Tags: list, tree, prolog, logic

The specific problem is: Write the predicate
`sum(T,S)` to mean that the tree `T` has a root-to-leaf path with sum `S`.

I am solving the `pathsum` problem in Prolog but I am stuck as to what I am doing wrong.

```
sum(T,S) :- mySum(T,S).

mySum([], S) :- S is 0.

mySum([H|T], S) :-
    nth0(X, H, Elem), 
    S1 is S-Elem,
    mySum(T, S1).

sum([1,2,3],3). is supposed to return yes/true.
sum([1,2,3] 4). is supposed to return yes/true.
sum([1,2,3] 6). is supposed to return no/false.
```

Comment: I don't see trees here, only lists? What is the logic of the three examples on the bottom? Are they somehow lists that magically turn into trees (following, I can only imagine, some non-arbitrary logic)?

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @User9213 you have not given any trees, but list.

Based on your examples the tree is

```
   1
  / \
 2   3
```

which would be `t(1,2,3)` with `t(Root,Left,Right)`

Normally you see a tree traversal that does both the left and then the right in the same predicate, but for this you need to do either the left or the right so two predicates can be used, or `;` can be used. This answer uses two predicates instead of `;` . Also this needs a base case to stop traversing the tree when a leaf node is found.

```
% Traverse left branch of tree
sum(t(Root,Left,_Right),[left|Path0],Sum) :-
    sum(Left,Path0,Left_sum),
    Sum is Root + Left_sum.

% Traverse right branch of tree
sum(t(Root,_Left,Right),[right|Path0],Sum) :-
    sum(Right,Path0,Right_sum),
    Sum is Root + Right_sum.

% Base case to stop traversing the tree
sum(N,[],N) :-
    N \= t(_Root,_Left,_Right).
```

The code above also includes the path used to produce the result. Even though it was not requested, it is nice to have when the tree grows past several levels.

Example with paths.

```
?- sum(t(1,2,3),Path,Sum).
Path = [left],
Sum = 3 ;
Path = [right],
Sum = 4 ;
false.
```

Added predicate to solve your specific problem.

```
sum_1(T,V) :-
    sum(T,_Path,V).
```

Example run:

```
?- sum_1(t(1,2,3),3).
true ;
false.

?- sum_1(t(1,2,3),4).
true ;
false.

?- sum_1(t(1,2,3),6).
false.
```

The `false` after `true` are due to backtracking but are correct results.